# expected value for the number of elements in difference of a random subset and a fixed subset

Tags: probability, expectation

I have a set $X=\{1,...,n\}$. Let $A\subseteq X$ be a fixed subset with $|A|=m$.  Now, I select $m$ values with replacement from $X$. Let $B$ denotes this random subset and $|B|$ be the random variable for the number of distinct elements in $B$. What is the expected value for the number of distinct elements in $B−A$? Is this true that
$$E(|B−A|)=E(|B|)(1−\frac{m}{n})?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability that a fixed element is in $B$ is $p=1-(1-1/n)^m$.
So the expectation of $|B|$ is $n$ times this $np$ (linearity of expectation). There are $m-n$
elements outside $A$ so the expectation of $|B-A|$ is $(m-n)p$
(linearity of expectation again).

Comment: Thanks. I think in your solution the expectation of $|B|$ is not true. In fact $E(|B|)=n(1-(1-1/n)^m)$. Note that I select $m$ values one at the time from $X$ with replacement.

Comment: @Sam now corrected.

Comment: Thanks again. Why $E(|B-A|)=(n-m)p$? Can you solve this part in details?

Comment: @Sam $|B-A|$ is the sum of $n-m$ indicator functions of the events $[x\in B]$ over all the $x\in X-A$.

Comment: Correct. What's your opinion about this problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2241532/276715